# Intersect Anonymous Types with Lambda Comparer

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'd like to perform an intersect on two arrays of anonymous types by comparing on one property. The collections are arrays of an anymous type that has two properties Id and Name. For example, given collection one:

```
{ 1, "Bob",
  2, "Jane",
  3, "Fred" }
```

and collection two:

```
{ 2, "",
  3, "",
  4, "" }
```

is it possible to write an Intesect statement to grab the intersection based on Id and take the name that isn't blank, so the result would be

```
{ 2, "Jane",
  3, "Fred" }
```

Right now I have

```
var data = one.Intersect(two, (x, y) => x.Id == y.Id).ToArray();
```

but I don't know how to handle the Name resolution or how to do the comparison on the fly with a lambda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you're looking for with a `Join`...

```
var data = one.Join(two,
                    a => a.Id,
                    b => b.Id,
                    (a, b) => new
                    {
                        Id = a.Id,
                        Name = string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Name) ? b.Name : a.Name
                    }).ToArray();
```

**Fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/zHUE3n**